# Insert grid on tikz picture with standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, grids

I'd like to insert a grid to fill the whole picture. I'm trying to mimic a blueprint paper.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why the use of colored rectangle change the border around picture?
2. Why the grid is much bigger than the picture size? In some sense, the anchors are not working.

[image][image]

**Edit:** using the `current bounding box` as suggested by Phelype Oleinik, the grid is over the draw. But the space around produced by the background rectangle is out of the grid.

[image]

**MWE**

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
background rectangle/.style={fill=green},
show background rectangle, %% <-- insert space around
]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,4) -- (0,3) -- cycle;    

\draw[white,step=.5cm]   (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\draw[white,step=.5cm]   (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);`. That is, use the picture's `current bounding box` instead of the `current page`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, nice!. In this case, the grid is over the picture, but not over the page. I supposed that the space around the picture created by the colored background was part of the picture, so should be included in the bounding box.

Comment: I *think* this happens because the `backgrounds` library defines the `show background rectangle` as `\tikzstyle{show background rectangle}=[execute at end picture=\tikz@background@framed]`, which does the framing *after* the picture is created and the bounding box is set, that's why the grid does not span the outer rectangle. You could use something to enlarge the bounding box prior to the end of the picture, then draw the grid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backgrounds` library offers two option `show background rectangle` and `show background grid` (or `gridded`) which can be combined to obtain the desired result.

Initially separation between figure and background rectangle is `.5ex`, but `tight background` forces it to `0pt`.

If `background rectangle` is filled, `background grid` should be drawn after it.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  mybackground/.style={%
    tight background, % 0pt margins around figure
    background rectangle/.style={fill=green},
    background grid/.style={draw=white, step=2mm, ultra thin},
    show background rectangle,
    show background grid % after a filled background rectangle
  }%
}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[mybackground]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,4) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `standalone` class, by default, puts everything inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}` in an `\hbox`, then crops the page to the size of this `\hbox`. When you use the `current page` hook, the page is not yet cropped, so the full size is used.

Then, as I said in the comment, you can switch to the `current bounding box` hook, so the grid is drawn around the picture only, and the boxing of `standalone` is correct.

But then the grid does not span the whole page, just the picture because you used the `show background rectangle` option, which does:

```
\tikzstyle{show background rectangle}=[execute at end picture=\tikz@background@framed]
```

*after* the picture is created and the bounding box is set, so the `current bounding box` looks smaller than the "`actual bounding box`".

You can, however, tell Ti*k*Z to execute some piece of code after the picture is created. You just have to assure that the grid is drawn *after* the `show background rectangle` is executed:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  blueprint/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[white,step=.5cm] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
      \end{scope}
    }%
  }%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  inner frame sep = 0.5cm, % to make the grid match the border
  show background rectangle,%% <-- insert space around
  blueprint,% This MUST be after "show background rectangle"
  background rectangle/.style={fill=green},
  ]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,4) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Very nice and explanatory answer.

Comment: In this case, the grid will be over any other draw? Some of it lines are hiding other drawn lines in my case (not in the MWE).

Comment: @Sigur I got distracted by the rest and forgot about this :) You have to tell Ti*k*Z to draw the grid on the background as John did. I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Oh, now it is ok. So, since the trick was the background layer, do you mind if I accept his answer? Also, it is short.

Comment: @Sigur No, I don't mind :), go for which best fits your needs. I'm no Ti*k*Z expert either, the fun part was figuring out what `standalone` did :). Note, however, that John's answer removes the border around the picture. The extra code I used was to keep the border on.

Comment: Well observed about *keeping the border*. Anyway, thanks. Difficulty to choose an answer. :)

Comment: @Sigur As I said, go for the one that solves your problem. No worries :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,4) -- (0,3) -- cycle;    

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[green]   (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\draw[white,step=.5cm]   (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Interesting and simple solution.